# Do Windows Installation ISOs only work with certain Keys

Tags: windows, oem

If I have a retail license key for Windows XP/Vista/7/8 will it work with a OEM ISO based disk or vice versa? Or are all Windows versions the same?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/351278/can-i-activate-windows-xp-pro-installed-from-retail-or-vl-media-with-oem-key?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Vista and above, you can use any disk as long as the version (i.e. Home Premium, Pro, etc) is the same as the sticker; OEM and Retail will treat the keys the same.

With Windows XP, it matters if it is the Retail, VLK or OEM versions, so you will need to be careful there. The VLK is only available to enterprise customers, and will only activate Pro (XP) or the Enterprise licenses (Vista, 7 and 8)